# How to make the ActionBar LayoutParams workable for the android 2.x devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-2.2-froyo, layoutparams

I have successfully created an application which is workable on the >3.0 devices. However, I need to make the application also function-able on the 2.x devices. I would like ask if it is possible to make the ActionBar.LayoutParams also functionable on those devices.

Does there have any compatibility package available to make it functionable?

Anyone idea is welcome...

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock is what you're looking for. It will allow you to use the action bar on 2.x+ devices:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: I tried to use ActionBarSherlock as a library for my project. However,  after adding ActionBarSherlock as a library, the R.java for my project is missing....

Comment: Yeah, that means your compiler failed to compile the code because of some kind of error. The R.java file is generated upon a successful build. If you're in Eclipse, go to the Problems tab. If it's not open, go to Window > Show View > Problems   After you fix the problem, you'll be able to automatically generate your R.java file.

Comment: there is only one type of error :r cannot be resolved to a variable... I think that the problem occurs because there is no R.java generated..

Comment: Yeah, and R.java can't be generated if there are other errors within the code. Try performing a Clean. Project > Clean